# split numpy array into equal pieces when size of array is not divisible

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a wav file. I would like to split this audio into 20 sn equal pieces to read and get meta info. I have done this in Matlab but I want to do it in python3.6. fs is the sample frequency in the code. Here is my working matlab code;

```
    [y, fs] = audioread(file)
    windowsize=20*fs;
    trailingsamples=mod(length(y), windowsize);
    sampleframe=reshape(y(1:end-trailingsamples), windowsize, []);

    siz=size(sampleframe);
    nseg=siz(2);  % nseg=NumberOfSegments 

    for i=1:nseg  
            yseg=sampleframe(:,i);
      %extract meta info here...
```

In python I tried;

```
        from scipy.io import wavfile
        fs, data = wavfile.read(file)

        windowsize=20*fs;
        trailingsamples=len(data)%windowsize
```

This is where I get stuck. I thought using `np.split(data, windowsize)` but 'data' has trailing samples in it. I need my python code does the same tasks as Matlab code. thanks